# Fresh install on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on RAID 0 using LVM not booting

Tags: boot, raid, lvm

Just created 2 HDD drives 1TB RAID 0 array with bios after starting installation from USB stick everythings works just fine on partitioning page selected LVM with no encryption and LVM gives me report for the new partitioning sheme and i wright it.afterward installation starts normally until the end after finishes and restarting the pc cannot boot it shows up vgubuntu group not found and drops to a shell in initramfs.
So please help what to do?